# What is the valid way to bind per-object uniform buffers (e.g. camera matrices)?

Tags: vulkan

I have some simple vulkan app which have:

- 3 command buffers for each swapchain image (#1, #2, #3)
- 1 uniform buffer with projection matrix data

I want to bind uniform buffer once. i'm using command buffer #1 to bind uniform buffer:

```
   begin();
   bindDescriptorSets();
   end();
   submit();
   waitIdle();
   reset();
```

Then i record commands for each swapchain image (3 times):

```
   begin()
   bindVertexBuffers()
   beginRenderPass()
   bindPipeline()
   draw()
   endRenderPass()
   end();
```

Drawing works as expected, but validation layer logs an error:

```
[ UNASSIGNED-CoreValidation-DrawState-DescriptorSetNotBound ] Object: 0x1a57aad7910 (Type = 6) | VkPipeline 0x21 uses set #0 but that set is not bound.
```

If i move the `bindDescriptorSets();` line to the second recording block, like this:

```
   begin()
   bindDescriptorSets();
   bindVertexBuffers()
   beginRenderPass()
   bindPipeline()
   draw()
   endRenderPass()
   end();
```

Validation is OK, but there is no difference in rendering.

So, the question is: do i have to bind descriptor sets for each buffer recording? If yes, why does the app work fine when i'm binding descriptor sets once?

Comment: "*waitIdle*" That is a thing you should *never do*.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it relates to the current state of the Vulkan application. Let's see what specification says about the state:

> 2.2.1. Queue Operation
>
> Commands recorded in command buffers either perform actions (...), set state (bind pipelines, **descriptor sets**,
> and buffers, set dynamic state, push constants, set render
> pass/subpass state), or perform synchronization (...). Some commands
> perform more than one of these tasks. State setting commands update
> the current state of the command buffer.

Notice I marked in bold that binding a descriptor set is a *state command*.

You bind descriptor set to a command buffer end that buffer and submit. Next, you start other command buffers. Let's see again what specification tells us about the command buffers:

> 5. Command Buffers
>
> Each command buffer manages state independently of other command buffers. There is no inheritance of state across primary
> and secondary command buffers, or between secondary command buffers.
> When a command buffer begins recording, all state in that command
> buffer is undefined.

So the specification and layers tell you that you have to bind descriptors to every command buffer that uses that state. Why it works even with warnings? I don't know, probably your implementation allows it, but I wouldn't recommend to keep it as it is.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought that setting the state every frame is some overhead. With opengl there is no need to do such thing. Does it mean that opengl driver does the same (sets the state) every frame in the background?

Comment: I don't know, I never programmed OpenGL. But I would not be surprised if the driver remembers the state and, yes, set it every "frame".

Comment: There are two things - creating the states, and binding a state to be used. State creation is expensive, state binding is cheap. OpenGL ES basically does dynamic state creation and state binding (pretty much anything is mutable just prior to draw time). Vulkan does pre-creation of most states, so really all you have to do is binding (which is mostly just setting a set of pointer indirections and so is really fast).